# Can one rail app use multiple Resque (in different engines) and multiple redis instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have my rails app , where my different services are in different different engines .I want to use different resque (and different redis and different workers) for my different engines .How to do it in rails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not shared any code, I am not sure how you have structured your app and how are you using Redis and workers. Hence I will have to assume many things while answering this question.

Let's say your structure is like this

```
root
  engines
    engine1
      app
      config
      ...
    engine2
      app
      config
      ...
```

You can keep resque config like this

resque1 config with redis running of localhost on port 6380

```
#root/engines/engine1/config/resque.yml 
development: localhost:6379 #redis1
test: localhost:6379
...
```

resque2 config with redis running of localhost on port 6380

```
#root/engines/engine2/config/resque.yml 
development: localhost:6380 
test: localhost:6380
...
```

rescue1 initializer

```
#root/engines/engine1/config/initializers/resque.yml
rails_root = File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'
config_file = rails_root + '/engines/engine1/config/resque.yml'

resque_config = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(config_file)).result)
Resque.redis = resque_config[rails_env]
```

rescue2 initializer

```
#root/engines/engine2/config/initializers/resque.yml
rails_root = File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'
config_file = rails_root + '/engines/engine2/config/resque.yml'

resque_config = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(config_file)).result)
Resque.redis = resque_config[rails_env]
```

You can start workers like this

```
RAILS_ENV=production resque-web rails_root/engines/engine1/config/initializers/resque.rb
RAILS_ENV=production resque-web rails_root/engines/engine2/config/initializers/resque.rb
```

Also, If you want to use a **single redis and resque instance** then, for redis you can namespace it https://github.com/resque/redis-namespace
and for resque you can define different sets of queues for each engine.

Comment: even after doing above changes , if i enqueue my engine1 job , it still goes to  /app/config/initializers/resque.rb redis url  and not to my engine/config/initializers/resque.rb redis url. Somewhere its getting override.Also , we are using only one instance of Resque through out our code base, how does only one instance of Resque will point to different redis urls in different engines ?

Comment: while starting the resque you have to specify the path of the initializer otherwise it will look on a default path which is `/app/config/initializers/resque.rb` anyways since you are using single resque then its not possible to connect multiple Redis with same resque instance (although I have not used resque but its not possible anyway)  and why do you want to do such thing it doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Still, if you want to do that then you have to modify resque gem to support such feature (in sidekiq this feature is available). Use that modified version of your gem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same redis with `different namesapces` for each engine.
Or if memory of the redis is your concen, you can trying using [redis connection pool gem](https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool).